# How to use the lambda function instead of for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 for loops running over some data and eventually, counts row number and accumulated `df` for some operation. The code is here,

```
def preprocess(dfs, functions):
    storage = []
    row = 0

    for df in dfs:
        for func in functions:
            df = func(df)
        row += row + df.shape[0] 
        storage.append(df)

    df = pd.concat(storage, ignore_index=True)
    return row, df
```

Can I use `lambda` function to reduce the code and make more elegant and better performing ?

Comment: `lambda` is not a performance feature. Using more lambdas in your code will not make it faster.

Comment: A lambda is just a way to create a function in an expression, where the function body only contains a single `return <expression>` statement. Calling a function has overhead, so using a lambda is *not* going to make things faster if you didn't have a function there before.

Comment: Okay, I get that. What is the point of the -4? This question is not that bad I guess. You just ruined this account.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do `row += row + df.shape[0]`? Shouldn't that be `row +=df.shape[0]` or `row = row + df.shape[0]`?

Comment: @PM2Ring Now, this is good point out here.

Comment: Your question isn't fantastic, but IMHO it certainly doesn't deserve 4 downvotes (and I'm almost certain that none of the commenters have downvoted, it's not their style). However, some people think "how do I make this working code run faster" questions should be on Code Review, not SO. Or maybe you got downvoted for not doing sufficient research to learn that `lambda` isn't a performance enhancement feature, and it's certainly not a replacement for a `for` loop.

Comment: And, many of those people never bother to write a single answer. I seriously love SOF, but, this place is getting slightly hostile these days. I use SOF quite sometime and this is not that type of bad question. Though, I admit I should have done better research before asking question.

Comment: Please, have a look in my answer and if you think this is at least okay, up vote the question. This will help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer as I get several down votes and none of them answers the question. This is certainly possible to do with lambda, though, it may not improve the performance.

```
def preprocess(dfs, functions):
    d = [map(lambda func: func(df), functions) for df in dfs]
    df = pd.concat(d[-1], ignore_index=True)
    return df.shape[0], df
```